# How to sum different categorical data of a data frame into different column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to add "R", "F" and "M" into a single column. suppose if any record has R = 1, F = 1 and M = 1 then I want 3. But when I am doing

```
rfm['RFM_Score'] = rfm[['R','F','M']].sum(axis = 1)
print(rfm['RFM_Score'].head())
```

I am getting 111.0 instead of 3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What are the datatypes of the columns `R`,`F` and `M`?

Comment: I'm guessing they are strings.  Try `rfm[['R', 'F', 'M']].appy(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
rfm['RFM_Score'] = rfm[['R']].astype(int)+rfm[['F']].astype(int)+rfm[['M']].astype(int)
```

Or you can even use:

```
rfm[['R', 'F', 'M']].appy(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` preferred.  There are too many opportunities to run into an error with `astype(int)` or `astype(float)` that `pd.to_numeric` handles for you.

Comment: Ya, to_numeric is handy to use when there is non-numeric characters at some indices for the given column

Comment: rfm[['R', 'F', 'M']].appy(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1) This is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like those are strings rather than numeric, so try:

`rfm['RFM_Score'] = rfm[['R','F','M']].astype(float, errors='ignore').sum(axis = 1)`

Comment: Do you know why pandas does that "string sum" in such a way?

Comment: possibly you have non-numeric values in some rows for those columns. you can specify a  dtype argument with explicit types per column if you are using read_csv to load this data.

Comment: I meant to ask do you know why pandas sums `"1", "2", "8"` as a string concatanation first but then casts the result to `float` if it can.

Comment: ah ok. So my understanding is that it is a case of operator overloading: for strings in Python, the plus operator means concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution, however I verified with some test data and this should work:

```
rfm['RFM_Score'] = rfm['R'] + rfm['F'] + rfm['M']
```

I'm afraid I'm not exactly positive why it's concatenating your values there rather than summing them.  I'm still learning myself, and I've found sometimes the most intuitive manner with some of those functions does not give the intuitively expected result.  Hope this helps tho!  Good luck!

Edit:  I saw someone point out that it's likely those numeric values are strings rather than int, and that would definitely explain the concatenation.